# Window Message Notification - Language and Locale

Tags: windows, localization, windows-messages

I want to find out what win message is / are sent when we change the locale settings, Date Time and Language in particular.

I know when window Theme is changed we receive WM_THEMECHANGED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WM_SETTINGSCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for locale settings and [WM_TIMECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for time changes.

You will get [WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before the language is changed (and you can choose whether to accept or reject the change), and then [WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after the language is successfully changed (if you pass WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST to the DefWindowProc).

Answer (score 0):

[WM_TIMECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is sent whenever system time is changed.

[WM_SETTINGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also sent upon change of some modifications. However, it's done on a volunteer base by the app that changes the setting. One can assume standard Control Panel applets are fair players.

Comment: And for language is it WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST OR WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE ?